# Open MS office Document inside AIR Application

Tags: air

I want to open MS office Document (.xlsx,.docx,.pptx) inside AIR Application. Is it Possible ?.
I am using AIR 2.5.1. Please give me some suggestion about this.

Thanks,
Mani

---

Thanks for your reply. Yes. i knew about Nativeprocess for opening MS office application. but i want to open MS document inside AIR application. (example: we can open MS office document inside IE browser with ActiveX support). i want similar like that to open inside AIR application.

Comment: Without convertion (like doc to swf). i want to open winword.exe file inside AIR.

Comment: Do you want to open MS office document with MS office application launched by AIR application Or You want to open MS office documents inside AIR application.

For first case you can use nativeprocess [http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/quickstart/articles/interacting_with_native_process.html]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes. i knew about Nativeprocess for opening MS office application. but i want to open MS document inside AIR application. (example: we can open MS office document inside IE browser with ActiveX support). i want similar like that to open inside AIR application.